# Double clicking on the datagrid's row fires application in break mode

Tags: wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid in WPF which binds data from the database. Well when I double click on the datagrid's row it fires the application in break mode. How can I disable this default functionality?

Answer (score 0):

First create a class and datagrid columns bind with the class attributes and set the values of class attributes in mainwindow.xaml.cs and datagrid.selected item as class object list.
    List list=new List();
    foreach(var item in database)
    {
         list.add(new className(){ abc=item.abc,});
    }
    datagrid.itemssource=list;